# C# SVG (using device-cmyk() or icc-color()) to PDF Conversion

Tags: c#, pdf, svg

I am attempting perform what I think would be a simple task.  Convert an SVG to PDF.

The only stipulation is that the converter needs to use the device-color() values or the icc-color() values specified in the SVG.

I have searched and searched for solutions with no luck. The solutions I have found will convert using the sRGB values of the SVG and not the cmyk values.

I have looked into Batik, Inkscape, Scribus, IText, and Cairo.

Update ****

altSoft XML2PDF looks promising.  Their tech support has been good and they say their new release has this feature.  We will see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got this working with a commercial solution with altsoft XML2PDF.  We worked with their dev team and got this functionality integrated with a number of other features as well

http://www.alt-soft.com/

Thanks to Evgeny and the team at alt-soft.com

Comment: Hi Brett. I was looking for a solution for this as well but I'd definitely prefer a Java solution. Did you ever get anywhere with Batik or try adding the feature since it's open source? I see that FOP [supports CMYK](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/extensions.html#color-function-cmyk) and there's also a [color branch of Batik](https://www.mail-archive.com/batik-dev@xmlgraphics.apache.org/msg03215.html). I'm about to try these out.

Comment: I didn't.  I ended up just paying for this software because I was spinning my wheels and the cost was worth it.  They provided excellent support for their product and even added custom features for us.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Good to know. For anybody else who comes across this, I did have luck with Batik's branch and I tested with both device-cmyk and icc-named-color to add both uncalibrated CMYK colors and named spot colors into a PDF by including these additional colors in the SVG.